# ThinkTecture IdentityServer and identity federation

Tags: single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect

I'am trying to enter in the huge world of the SSO and making things to be clearer.
Here is my use case :

I have a web app (the RP in the SSO jargon) which uses a REST API. We have customers that would like to use a SSO way to connect to our web application and our API.

For example, a user "A" from our customer "A-Company" is connected to its intranet. And in this intranet there's a link to our Web App. If this user A clics on it the Web App must redirect it to the IDP of the "A-Company". User A then signin and gets an access token and is redirected back to our web app. Then, our web app validate this access token, get the claims and etc ...

If a user "B" from our customer "B-Compagny" wants to do the same, it'll have to be redirected to its own IDP too.

How this can be achieve using IdentityServer3? How my WebApp (the RP) knows where to redirect the incoming request to be authenticated (to IDP-A or IDP-B or elsewhere ...)

Is this use case illustrates what is called "Identity federation"?

I was looking at OpenID Connect and ThinkTecture IdentityServer V3 that seem to be a very good product but I have some difficulties to see if it will fit my needs.

Thank you for your help

Fred